# How do I "pull up" the root bone one level?

Tags: armature, interface, bones

I have a lot of meshes that have an extra bone at the root level:

[image]

Unfortunately, this makes it impossible for them to share an Avatar in Unity since they'll all have that extra randomly named transform in there (in this case "Undefined 1_7813"). What I want is to make "hip" the root bone. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just delete the 'Undefined' bone?

Comment: What you're showing has a single root bone ("hip" in this case.)  "Undefined1_7813" is not a bone; it is your armature object.  I don't know exactly what problem you're having, but it is not that you have an extra bone.  Make sure your armature has no transforms (loc/rot/scale); after that, I would recommend asking in sites devoted to Unity about what's going on.